# Migrate Data from Ondedrive to iCloud Photos

Tags: onedrive, photos, migration, cloud-storage, icloud

My OneDrive contains pretty much all of my files, photos and videos (~60+ gb). I have a mac and an iPhone and I finally want to sync up everything all in iCloud. I've already upgraded my iCloud so it has enough space.

The files I can move manually and are fairly easily since they are not as large. I can download them and upload them. But is there a way that I can transfer my photos and videos from OneDrive to iCloud. The iCloud photo library also contains photos from the past so all the photos would need to merge as well in iCloud.

Comment: Requests for product or service recommendations are off topic here. I have removed this portion of your question.

Comment: sorry, do you know where I could get some product recommendations?